# sudo dpkg --configure -a get stuck.

Tags: bash, dpkg, openjdk, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was trying to install jre-8-headless. For that I gave this command

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre-headless
```

on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows.

It it was stopped at some step. I have waited several minutes(about 15 minutes) then I closed the window without completing the task.
Now when I am trying to install something or giving `update` command, it says

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

When I am giving the command

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

it is showing a line: `Setting up openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64 (8u91-b14-0ubuntu4~14.04) ...` and is doing nothing and get stucked.

How to solve this?

Comment: Is the drive light on your computer on or blinking? How long did you wait?

Comment: I ran into this problem too! Had it running overnight

Comment: Try running `sudo dpkg --debug=77777 --configure -a` and see what the last bit of output is before it gets stuck.

Comment: simular issue with on Debian I run `sudo dpkg --debug=77777 --configure -a` then I deleted the file `/var/lib/dpkg/info/apt.postinst` which was stuck